# When is the "flat limit" of a submanifold not a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, compactness, geometric-measure-theory, submanifold

We have a compactness result, where the "flat limit" of an integral current is itself an integral current. (with some conditions)

Now I am curious about submanifolds. I am expecting that an equivalent result does not hold for submanifolds in general. However I am having trouble finding a resource to verify this. Does anyone know of an example, book or article I could check out?

Comment: Chodosh has GMT notes that show flat *chains* of top dimension is isometric to $L^1$.

Comment: @Mr.Brown thank you! I'll check them out.